# Compiling Qt project into Eclipse using Cygwin compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded Eclipse with the plug-in to work with C/C++ over Windows. I downloaded Cygwin (base and devel mostly) and works ok for a hello world application.

Now I want to work with Qt. Instead of downloading the framework, I downloaded the libraries "Qt libraries 4.8.0 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 354 MB)", since the other option was the same thing for Visual Studio. I know this could be part of the problem, since it looks to be made only for minGW compiler. If I need to do things in a different way, please tell.

Then I restarted computer, opened Eclipse, wrote this Qt hello world for a new C++ application with Cygwin compiler:

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char * args[] )
{
    cout << "Here goes!" << endl;

    QApplication app( argc, args );
    QPushButton hello( "Hello World!", 0 );
    hello.resize( 100, 50 );
    app.setMainWidget( &hello );
    hello.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

And compiler doesn't find the .h files included. Could it need me to add Qt\bin path to the enviroment variables?

Maybe I should stick to the Qt framework, as it looks like a compiler itself (I really don't know how that works, since yesterday I thought Qt was just a library).

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong (I hope answer to this is not "EVERYTHING" hehe) and how can I make this work.

Comment: did installed the plugin for integrating eclipse with qt?

Comment: I did, and I have also added the Qt\bin folder to PATH in enviroment variables. Also installed MinGW as most tutorials explain instead of using Cygwin. Nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QT framework implements a meta-language over the top of C++ which QT uses to create its event handling framework (google qt slots and signals for more information). Standard compilers such as G++ don't understand this meta-language so it has to be translated first. You can do this through eclipse by maintaining your own makefile and running QT's Meta-Object-Compiler over the top of the code before you compile it (see [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) for more details).

My approach would be to use the QTCreator toolkit to do your compilation, even if you don't use it as your IDE. Also consider using Eclipse and [qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html), which if I remember correctly, automatically uses the MOC translater as part of its process.

Good luck!

Comment: So, I should use Qt's qmake as my compiler, and not Cygwin or minGQ. I guess that's what QTCreator does beneath. Is that right? In that case, how can I use qmake as my compiler from Eclipse? It is not listed as an option when I select a compiler tool when creating a new project.

Comment: no you use both. qmake process Qt specific keywords and generate C++ files (and a makefile), then your compiler use the makefile for the files. Your question is nice but Qtcreator is so much more appropriate imho.

Comment: I have to agree with UmNyobe. In theory you could set up eclipse to use qmake as a build system. However, it would probably be a lot more bother than just using QTCreator. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775398/eclipse-qt-and-c-project-is-it-possible)